# multi-line label in enumitem: make list content vertically align with the first line of label

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, enumitem

Title describes my goal, so far the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,
                    align=right,
                    ]
\item[label 0] \lipsum[75]
\item[\begin{tabular}{c}
            label 1 1st line\\
            label 1 2nd line
        \end{tabular}] \lipsum[75]

\item[\smash{\begin{tabular}{c}
                 label 2 1st line\\
                 label 2 2nd line
             \end{tabular}}] \lipsum[75]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

`\smash` and `tabular` help me getting closer to the goal but still, the 1st line of list content align with the mid point of the label (not 1st line):

[image]

How do I align the 1st line of list content with 1st line of the label to have the following effect?

```
            labe 0     { content of label 0 }

1st line of labe 1     { content of label 1; content of label 1;
2nd line of labe 1     content of label 1; content of label 1; c
                       ontent of label 1 }
```

Ideally the vertical spacing of label and content should matched, and this is why I also hope to eventually get rid of `tabular` since it adds extract space both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Try with `\begin{tabular}[t]{c} …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may liked the following solution which not use `tabular` for formation of item labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{right}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedleft #1}}} % <--
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=8em,
                    align=right,
                    leftmargin=!,
                    ]
\item[label 0] \lipsum[75]
\item[label 1 1st line\\                % <--
      label 1 2nd line]     \lipsum[75] % <--

\item[label 2 1st line\\
      label 2 2nd line]     \lipsum[11]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Used definition of `right` have sense and influence only in case if any of list is formatted with options:

```
[labelwidth=8em, % <---
 align=right,
 leftmargin=!,   % <---
 ]
```

however, you can limit `\SetLabelAlign` to some local group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
{ % <-- start of local group
\SetLabelAlign{right}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedleft #1}}} 
\begin{description}[labelwidth=8em,
                    align=right,
                    leftmargin=!,
                    ]
\item[label 0] \lipsum[75]
\item[label 1 1st line\\
      label 1 2nd line]     \lipsum[75]

\item[label 2 1st line\\
      label 2 2nd line]     \lipsum[66]
\end{description}
} % <-- end of local group
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1]    \lipsum[66]
\item[22]   \lipsum[66]
\item[333]  \lipsum[66]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
\item[test] \lipsum[66]
\item[longer item label]    \lipsum[66]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also provide the code to undo `SetLabelAlign` (set to default) afterwards?

Comment: @Rahn, this definition not harm option `align=right` any of lists. It has influence only with option, where you determine `label width` and `leftmargin`, in your case:  `[labelwidth=8em,
                    align=right,
                    leftmargin=!,
                    ]`. Anyway, iy fill more comfortable, you can inclose redefinition of `right` in some local group. See edit in answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,
                    align=right,
                    ]
\item[label 0] \lipsum[75]
\item[\smash{\Longunderstack{ label 1 1st line\\
            label 1 2nd line}}] \lipsum[75]

\item[\smash{\Longunderstack{
                 label 2 1st line\\
                 label 2 2nd line}}] \lipsum[75]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]